# Aligning elements in an embedded mailchimp signup form

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I am trying to embed a signup form in a page using the code I generated in MailChimp, but the results are different than what I am trying to obtain : the signup button doesn't appear, the width doesn't respect the 960px from the CSS, and the fonts are too close to the signup field.

Here is the code :

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup" align="center">
<form action="http://pmwd.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=228830d2daf74d54c2935571c&amp;id=f5f28b80a2" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>Recevez toutes nos offres et promotions avec la newsletter!
<div align="center">
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="votre adresse e-mail" required></div>
<div class="clear" align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Je m'abonne!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" ></div>
</form>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS :

```
#mc_embed_signup form {background:#fc6765; display:block; position:relative; text-align:center; padding:8px 0 8px 3%; width:960px; color: #FFFFFF; font-family: 'Helvetica, Arial',sans-serif; font-size: 25px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; border:10px double #fff; border-radius:10px}
#mc_embed_signup h2 {font-weight:bold; padding:0; margin:15px 0; font-size:14px;}
#mc_embed_signup input {border:1px solid #999; -webkit-appearance:none;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=checkbox]{-webkit-appearance:checkbox;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=radio]{-webkit-appearance:radio;}
#mc_embed_signup input:focus {border-color:#333;}
#mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both; background-color: #aaa; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:14px; font-weight: bold; height: 30px; padding:0; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto; width:125px; display: block; margin: 0 0 10px; min-width: 90px; width: 35%;}
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {background-color:#777;}
#mc_embed_signup .small-meta {font-size: 14px;}
#mc_embed_signup .nowrap {white-space:nowrap;}     
#mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:none; display:inline;}

#mc_embed_signup label {display:block; font-size:14px; padding-bottom:10px; font-weight:bold;}
#mc_embed_signup input.email {display:block; padding:8px 0; margin:0 4% 10px 0; text-indent:5px; width:58%; min-width:130px;}
#mc_embed_signup input.button {display:block; width:120px; margin:0 0 10px 0; min-width:125px;}

#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {float:left; top:-1.4em; padding:0em .5em 0em .5em; overflow:hidden; width:90%;margin: 0 5%; clear: both;}
#mc_embed_signup div.response {margin:1em 0; padding:1em .5em .5em 0; font-weight:bold; float:left; top:-1.5em; z-index:1; width:80%;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {color:#529214; display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup label.error {display:block; float:none; width:auto; margin-left:1.05em; text-align:left; padding:.5em 0;}
#mc-embedded-subscribe {display:block; float:none;}
```

but this is the result I get :

[image: the pink signup strip is the result I get when using above code, which doesn't look like what i am trying to get]

1-why isn't the signup button showing?
2-why isn't the width at 960?

thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your question? Also, please don't just post a link to your work. Your website may not be around for as long as Stack Overflow. If you post the relevant code here in your question, it makes it future-proof and useful.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to make my question more precise!